# Find client IP connected to VLAN from Cisco Catalyst 3600 by SNMP

Tags: networking, cisco, snmp, cisco-catalyst, oid

I would like to get using of course SNMP, list of client IPs connected to VLAN in Cisco Catalyst 3600.

So far, I have pseudo-algorithm made by me which obtains those IP addresses, but I am not sure if this is done in right way :

**1)** Receive all IP addresses from Catalyst (oid `1.3.6.1.2.1.4.20.1.2`) I get something like :

`IP-MIB::ipAdEntIfIndex.10.10.2.1 = INTEGER: 152`

`IP-MIB::ipAdEntIfIndex.10.10.2.251 = INTEGER: 152`

`IP-MIB::ipAdEntIfIndex.10.10.3.251 = INTEGER: 151` and so on.

**2)** Get ifIndex of VLAN (oid `1.3.6.1.2.1.4.20.1.2.10.10.2.1.<IP_ADDRESS>`) for particular IP address from above list :

`IP-MIB::ipAdEntIfIndex.10.10.2.1 = INTEGER: 152`

`IP-MIB::ipAdEntIfIndex.10.10.2.251 = INTEGER: 152`

`IP-MIB::ipAdEntIfIndex.10.10.3.251 = INTEGER: 151`

**3)** Get VLAN name (oid `1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.46.1.3.1.1.4.1.<IF_INDEX>`) If_index is borrowed from list above :

`IP-MIB::ipAdEntNetMask.152 = No Such Instance currently exists at this OID`

`IP-MIB::ipAdEntNetMask.151 = No Such Instance currently exists at this OID`

In the third step I have this problem, that instance can not be found in OID. It is weird, because for about forty IP addresses i can find about their 10 VLAN names to which they are connected. Or perhaps I am doing this wrong ?

Comment: ARP tables have the information as well, see: [Using SNMP to retrieve the ARP and mac-address tables from a switch](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2900/using-snmp-to-retrieve-the-arp-and-mac-address-tables-from-a-switch)

Answer (score 1):

I managed also obtain new algorithm to find those IPs connected to VLAN :

1) Obtain index value which uniquely identifies the interface to which this entry is applicable (oid : `1.3.6.1.2.1.4.20.1.2`)

Example output :

```
IP-MIB::ipAdEntIfIndex.10.10.2.1 = INTEGER: 152
IP-MIB::ipAdEntIfIndex.10.10.2.251 = INTEGER: 152
IP-MIB::ipAdEntIfIndex.10.10.3.250 = INTEGER: 151
IP-MIB::ipAdEntIfIndex.10.10.3.251 = INTEGER: 151
IP-MIB::ipAdEntIfIndex.10.100.0.1 = INTEGER: 312
IP-MIB::ipAdEntIfIndex.10.100.0.251 = INTEGER: 312
```

and so on...

2) Get name of interfaces on Catalyst 3600 using above index (oid : `1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.1.<INTERFACE_INDEX>`)

Example output (for index = *152*) :

```
IF-MIB::ifName.152 = STRING: Vl206
```

3) Extract IP address from step 1) for particular Interface index. For example for index *152* it will be IP addresses like :

```
10.10.2.1

10.10.2.251
```

connected to VLAN called *Vl206*

I hope that I did it well.

Comment: You can also use something like `snmp-server ifindex persist` and `snmp ifmib ifindex persist` on the device to make sure the interface indexes don't change if the device is restarted.